# Is it possible to create permanent object aliases

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I recently found myself using some rather lengthy names for the tables and views involved in a development piece, which got me wondering whether it's possible to create client/database/server level aliases for objects.

Say for example I have a view named *dbo.vAlphaBetaGammaDelta* . Is there a way (with or without Intellisense) to create a reference to it named *dbo.vABGD* ?

If not, would there be any downfalls to creating a view of a view or single table aside from maintenance necessary if/when the table schema changes?

I should note that these aliases/views would not be intended for use in other objects, but for alleviation and prevention of carpal tunnel during day-to-day troubleshooting and delving xD

Comment: using a less descriptive alias sounds counter-productive. Get a TSQL completion tool installed....

Comment: You mean Intellisense? It's an alias we refer to when speaking about the table, so really it isn't less descriptive. Again - just for delving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server allows for the creation of synonyms. That seems to be what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

However, as @MitchWheat mentioned. this seems to be going in the wrong direction. There are a few quite good SSMS plugins available that provide auto completion of long object names (e.g. SQL Prompt). Incidentally those products have trouble with synonyms...

Comment: Synonym is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Do you mean wrong only in that it results in extra unnecessary stuff?

Comment: Extra bang for your SYNONYM buck when referencing objects in four part names: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/

Comment: @ZokWobblefotz: Yes, that's what I meant with "wrong". However the layer of abstraction the Pinal mentions is a very good use case for synonyms.

Comment: To everyone commenting that this is the "wrong direction", imagine you have forty tables named alphalphalphahamhamsimilarnamesimlar, or think back to when tab completion doesn't fulfill on its promise because of so many similarly(long) named names. Its not the best, but what I am open to good ideas!

Answer (score 2):

There are many cases where you would like to have synonyms.
Let me state just one for start:
You have a well defined hypothetical name of a table: GlobalStatisticalRecord. Hundreds of lines of code and objects (keys, indexes, etc.) in SQL and elsewhere are referring to this table name.
After 5 years of usage, the abbreviation GSR was accustomed not only among the technical people, but also among the business users. So, to stress again, GSR is now even more recognizable than GlobalStatisticalRecord. However, for the new people that come into the technical team, it is good to keep the name GlobalStatisticalRecord as a table name, since it nicely describes what is the table all about. Now, when writing a quick **adhoc** query - and that may not be from your tool of choice with all the Intellisense features you are accustom to - then these aliases are really saving your time (and "life" at 2am in the morning when you are frantically trying to diagnose a production problem).
Please, if you never faced a case when you would need this, just don't assume that there is none. 
I stressed the **adhoc** adjective, since I agree that in permanent queries (stored procedures, etc.), for the reasons you pointed out, it is advisable to use the full table names.

Comment: I'll add another reason. I have to work with a database that does not use proper names for tables names. They're named things like T02 or T99. I assume this is to obfuscate their purpose from end users that might have access to the tables. However, it is a nightmare to remember which tables are which when writing queries. Enter synonyms!